# Travel to Amsterdam on Schengen business visa for tourist purpose

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, schengen-visas, amsterdam

I am travelling back to India from Curacao and I've 9 hours layover at Amsterdam airport. I am planning to go outside of Airport for sight seeing.

I've valid Schengen business visa issued from Netherlands only.

So can I use this visa for tourist purpose for visiting Amsterdam?

What questions will immigration officer ask to me about my trip to Amsterdam?

Comment: Is it a multiple-entry visa that has been used before?

Comment: @o.m. Yes It is multiple-entry visa, But I've not used it before.

Comment: That's a real problem. THe **first** use of a multiple-entry visa should be in accordance with the application, afterwards you can make other trips.